# Django uploading image in custom template

Tags: django

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import VideoPost

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = VideoPost
        fields = ('category', 'title', 'slug', 'content', 'video', 'image',)
```

models.py

```
class VideoPost(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique = True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def _get_unique_slug(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(VideoPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def post_new(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.author = request.user
                post.published_date = timezone.now()
                post.save()
                return render(request, 'stories/post_detail.html')
        else:
            form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'stories/post_new.html', {'form': form})
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

MEDIA_URL = 'static/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media')
```

This is not on django built in admin page, I wanted to make a custom post template.
All other form inputs work just fine, and all the data are stored in db correctly except image.
the image field in database is always blank no matter what image I put in there, and even in my static/media/image path, it's empty.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure in the HTML form to have the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" set correctly. Otherwise the request.FILES will be empty.

Comment: Oh.... I see... I've been struggling with this for hours and hours, and that one line just solved the problem. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: No problem, and try to follow the django conventions.